# MSP Recaptcha issue with changing contact page title

Tags: magento2, recaptcha

I have tried to change the title of the contact us page to just Contact, i did this by copying the contact xml file to my local theme

> /Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

**and then updated**

```
<head>      
    <title>Contact</title>
</head>
```

**Why does this break msp/recaptcha module**

> **Magento Version 2.3.3**
>
> error message Incorrect Captcha
>   thanks

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: The error "incorrect captcha"

Comment: magento version ?/

Comment: @Phes can you please post the full file, I guess you are trying to override the contact form aswell, this is not nescesarry, since you are only canging the title.